# install4j not seeing .dll files

Tags: java, install4j

I am setting up an install4j script, one of the things I need it to do is to include several .dll files in the installation tree.  The files are in a folder which is already copied, but although the other files in there are included, the .dlls are not.

When looking at the folder containing the files via install4j, the .dlls are not showing up at all.

I've searched for an answer but I'm stumped.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Do the DLL files show up in the tree under Files->View Results? If yes, switch on "Enable extra verbose output" in the build step and check if the files are mentioned in the output.

Two more things to check:

- Double-click the directory entry in the file distribution tree, and check steps 3 and 4. Maybe the DLLs have been excluded explicitly or by suffix.
- If you have installation components, go to Files->Installation components and check if the DLLs are included in any component

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions - in the end I had to explicitly add the folder, excluding the files that were already seen elsewhere in the file tree.  I still have no idea why the dlls are 'invisible' there, even recreating the entire project didn't help!