# How to register .net dll in installer4j

Tags: install4j

I am using install4j for my project and i have couple of dll's which needs to be registered with regasm.exe (.net) any help would be much appreciated in this regards.

Comment: Check [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8210194/install4j-not-seeing-dll-files)

Comment: Hi Nadeem_MK, I did went through the same link earlier. My problem is dll files are shown but not registered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install4j will not automatically register installed DLL files.

You can use "Run executable or batch file" actions to invoke regasm.exe with the correct parameters in order to register your DLLs.